# Convert LatLng (the return value from computeoffset() ) to object literal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geometry

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(10.398671, -84.170756);   
 google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point, 100, 0);
```

The returned value from `computeoffset` is (..., ...). Then how to convert it to {lat: ..., lng: ...}?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry), the return result is also of type `LatLng` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) has methods for latitude and longitude:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(10.398671, -84.170756);   
var newpt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point, 100, 0);
var pt = {lat: newpt.lat(), lng: newpt.lng()};
```